# Loading Image onto TableViewCell using SDWebImage

Tags: swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am trying to load an image into a tableview cell dynamically using SD WebImage but the issue I encounter is:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

My tableview cell code:

```swift
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemImage")

        let itemImages = allImages.imageList[indexPath.row].itemImageUrl


        cell?.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: itemImages), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

        return cell!

    }
```

I could be completely wrong but I think the issue lies within `sd_setImage` because it seems to be getting the types confused which makes the expression ambiguous but I am confused to why.

***Model Code***

```
ItemCard

import Foundation

class ItemCard {

    var itemImageUrl : String?

    init(imageUrl : String?) {
        itemImageUrl = imageUrl
    }



}
```

```
ItemCardList

import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage


class ItemCardList {

    var imageList = [ItemCard]()

    init() {

        let item = ItemCard(imageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/giveaway-35c7b.appspot.com/o/listingPhotos%2F716hlFpxaWL._SY445_.jpg?alt=media&token=e69fca04-c0c0-404b-aa6f-5d35e3a5cd4d")


        imageList.append(item)

    }


}
```

Comment: Make sure you `itemImages` is a string. This line `let itemImages = allImages.imageList[indexPath.row].itemImageUrl` imply that it might be an url instead

Comment: It is string that is how I set up in my model code, which I have linked as well assuming it my be something to do with the model.

Comment: Because you're using Swift then i suggest you to use KingFisher instead of SDWebImage: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: @jacob I ended up changing the framework and it worked

Comment: Congrat, @Zubair Amjad, let give me an accepted answer or up vote for more motivation